# How exactly is the value of count(*) determined in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am joining a table of about 70000 rows with a slightly bigger second table through inner join each. Now count(a.business_column) and count(*) give different results. The former correctly reports back ~70000, while the latter gives ~200000. But this only happens when I select count(*) alone, when I select them together they give the same result (~70000). How is this possible?

```
select
   count(*)
   /*,count(a.business_column)*/

from table_a a
inner join each table_b b
   on b.key_column = a.business_column
```

Comment: Full queries please? Probably a exploding join, or nested structures being flattened?

Comment: Sorry, should have done that immediately. Like I said, 70000 is the correct number, the join does not explode. If nested joins are being flattened, then how?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** *For a step by step explanation on how this works, see* [BigQuery flattens when using field with same name as repeated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604080/bigquery-flattens-when-using-field-with-same-name-as-repeated-field/33621195#33621195) *instead*.

---

To answer the title question: COUNT(*) in BigQuery is always accurate.

The caveat is that in SQL COUNT(*) and COUNT(column) have semantically different meanings - and the sample query can be interpreted in different ways.

See: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/04/08/the-dangerous-subtleties-of-left-join-and-count-in-sql/

There they have this sample query:

```
select user.userid, count(email.subject)
from user
   inner join email on user.userid = email.userid
group by user.userid;
```

That query turns out to be ambigous, and the article author changes it for a more explicit one, adding this comment:

> But what if that’s not what the author of the query meant? There’s no
>   way to really know. There are several possible intended meanings for
>   the query, and there are several different ways to write the query to
>   express those meanings more clearly. But the original query is
>   ambiguous, for a few reasons. And everyone who reads this query
>   afterwards will end up guessing what the original author meant. “I
>   think I can safely change this to…”

---

**UPDATE:** *For a step by step explanation on how this works, see* [BigQuery flattens when using field with same name as repeated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604080/bigquery-flattens-when-using-field-with-same-name-as-repeated-field/33621195#33621195) *instead*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid you misunderstand my question. Sure count(\*) and count(column) behave differently with respect to null, that's the point of choosing count(\*). What I didn't expect and what I don't understand is that count(\*) is bigger than the number of rows, and that this changes when I select it along with count(column). I suspect that you could be right in your comment that this has got something to do with repeated fields being flattened, but that shouldn't happen, should it?

Comment: It happens because the query is ambiguous - and BigQuery needs to choose a way to interpret the query before calculating the result. Having the number change when you have one column or two is because the ambiguity is solved in 2 different ways, depending on which columns are part of the query. If you see the linked article, the sample query they use to show an example of ambiguity is remarkable similar to your query.

Comment: I still don't see the relevance of the sample query you cite. The only thing that is ambiguous there is the intent of the author, the query simply gives the number of non-null fields in email.subject. You're saying that in my example BigQuery resolves count(\*) differently depending on whether I also include count(column). But that doesn't answer my question *how* the resolution of count(\*) is affected by the inclusion of count(column). I don't see why one would ever want count(\*) to be anything else than the number of rows, which is *not* ambiguous.

Comment: I can't give a more specific answer because I can't reproduce your query and results. Can you repeat the experiment over public data, so me or someone else can reproduce the results you are getting? Then me (or someone else) would be able to give you the specific answer you are looking for.

Comment: I'll try. On the other hand, my question is fundamentally about how count(\*) is implemented in BigQuery, so anyone who knows that (i.a. the developers) wouldn't need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: For the general question, you already got my general answer. For a specific answer, you'll need to ask a specific question. For SQL fundamentals, please see the article linked in this answer. I am sure I could do more if you could provide the data that brought us to this point.

Answer (score 1):

COUNT(*) counts most repeated field in your query, if you want to count full records - use COUNT(0).

Comment: Is that documented? And how exactly does that work? Why does count(\*) give a different result from count(\*) followed by count(a.business_column)?

Comment: When I query `select count(*) from publicdata:samples.trigrams`, I get 68,051,509, which is precisely the number of rows, even though this table too has repeated fields. So what you're saying doesn't seem to be true, at least not in general.

Comment: COUNT(\*) counts most repeated field in the query, not in the table. Consider this query - select count(*) from publicdata:samples.trigrams where cell.value != 'foo', it will return 7,227,007,535 because it will count cell.value repeated field. count(0) in the same query would produce 68,051,509

Comment: So how precisely is this resolved technically? Why is `cell.value` deemed to be 'in the query' when the where clause references it but not otherwise? I assume the result set is not flattened, otherwise `count(0)` would have the same value. 

And most importantly, what you haven't anwered: how does this happen in my query, for I don't have a where clause and neither of the fields I join on are repeated? And why does the inclusion of `count(column)` affect `count(*)`?