# BigQuery flattens when using field with same name as repeated field

Tags: google-bigquery

***Edited to use public dataset***

I have a table with the following schema, which you can access here:
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/realself-main:rs_public.test_count
[image]

If I run the following query, I get a different result for *cnt1* vs. *cnt2*.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt1,
  COUNT(dr_id) as cnt2,
FROM (SELECT * FROM rs_public.test_count) AS tc
WHERE
  tc.is_published
```

[image]

If I remove the *tc* alias from the where clause, I get the same result for both counts:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt1,
  COUNT(dr_id) as cnt2,
FROM (SELECT * FROM rs_public.test_count) AS tc
WHERE
  is_published
```

[image]

If, however, I repeat the first query but use the *is_claimed* field in the where clause instead, I get the same count again.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt1,
  COUNT(dr_id) as cnt2,
FROM (SELECT * FROM rs_public.test_count) AS tc
WHERE
  tc.is_claimed
```

[image]

I think this is a bug and BigQuery is getting confused because *is_published* is an outer field and also a leaf field of the *cover_photos* record. It is incorrectly using the *cover_photos.is_published* field when evaluating whether the results should be flattened -- but using the outer *is_published* field when filtering the results per the where clause.

---

Here's the counter-example that doesn't use select *, which I reference in my comment on Felipe's answer below:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    dr_id,
    cover_photos.is_published
  FROM
    [realself-main:rs_public.test_count] )
```

returns 3.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*), COUNT(0)
FROM (
  SELECT
    dr_id,
    cover_photos.is_published
  FROM
    [realself-main:rs_public.test_count] )
```

returns 7 and 3! Per my comment, it seems like the only safe option is never to use count(*)

Comment: I had the same question, but despite setting a bounty I didn't manage to get an answer how precisely such queries are resolved... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483766/how-exactly-is-the-value-of-count-determined-in-bigquery

Comment: Thanks for linking to that question, @oulenz! That's exactly where I wanted to point @alan asking this new question, but I couldn't find it. For the question you asked, my last comment still stands: "For the general question, you already got my general answer. For a specific answer, you'll need to ask a specific question. For SQL fundamentals, please see the article linked in this answer. I am sure I could do more if you could provide the data that brought us to this point."

Comment: Just so I know (Im a jr) what does flatten mean in your terms?  When I think flatten I think denormalizing.

Comment: I think your last example is crucial. If the subselect were really flattened, `count(0)` and `count(*)` should both give 7. What we need is an explanation a to how exactly the two are calculated differently.

Answer (score 1):

If a query can be interpreted in many ways, BigQuery will do its best effort to guess what were your intentions - producing sometimes non-congruent results. This is true to every database, since SQL has space for these ambiguities.

Solution: Eliminate ambiguity from your queries - probably both results are correct, depending on what you are trying to count.

(eliminate ambiguity by not using *, and making the prefix explicit, while you could also make a explicit request on which ways you want the table flattened)

I would really like to comment on your specific data and results, but given that you haven't provided a public sample, I can't.

Comment: I am still befuddled how you can claim these queries are ambiguous. They are not, both are deterministic. The question is how they are resolved, and why they are resolved differently. Imo the result of the first query is simply wrong. If `dr_id` is a unique column, `count(*)` and `count(dr_id)` should always give the same result. In general, `count(*)` should always give the same result as `count(0)`. And if the BigQuery team disagrees, it should document how then `count(*)` is resolved. Until that time, `count(*)` is useless. And by saying "don't use `count(*)`" you're admitting as much.

Comment: If you give me a dataset I can look at, I can look and comment on the specific dataset. (btw, I did not say "don't use count(*)", and the confusion is my fault, as I didn't say the less ambiguous "don't use select *")

Comment: I apologise for misquoting you. (The point though stands, `count(*)` can't be used as long as its results are unpredictable.)

Comment: The point was that me (and probably the OP) don't understand how `count(*)` works in light of the above results, and so can't use it. Therefore I am not sure what exactly you want me to 'prove'?

Comment: I'm sorry @oulenz. I deeply apologize for my inability to express the idea "if you show me actual data, we will be able to continue this conversation". Please accept this video as a token of my limitations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTXyXuqfBLA.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I edited my question to use a public dataset that I created. I think this will add some clarity about the specific problem that I'm seeing. Also worth noting is that many of my queries are being generated by Looker, so that's why it's important for me to understand the specifics of why this isn't working.

Comment: count(*) is probably counting the most repeated field, in this case cover_photos.is_published - you have 1 null there and 6 values. 7 in total. Felipe's advice is spot on: if you want to count the number of records, you need to specify a field that exists only once per record.

Comment: And the difference between the two queries: in the first you reference is_published. in the second you don'tm so the outer count(*) doesn't see the repeated is_published.

Comment: @MichaelSheldon but the is_published I reference in the query isn't repeated; it's cover_photos.is_published that's repeated. I think BigQuery is getting confused about that too

Comment: @MichaelSheldon But why should `count(*)` do that? The expected behaviour is for it to return the number of records, and so give the same result as `count(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing a dataset @alan! Let's see how it looks:

[image]

It's an interesting table: It has 3 columns and 3 rows (tiny, but a normal SQL table). The interesting part is that the 3rd column can host nested records. On the first row it has nothing (null), the second row only has 1 value, and the third row has 5 different values nested.

Things get interesting when you start counting by column:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
3
```

That makes sense, the dataset has 3 rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(dr_id) 
FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
3
```

That also makes sense, there are 3 dr_id.

```
SELECT COUNT(cover_photos.is_published) 
FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
6
```

Now things got more interesting. It's 6, because there are 6 values for cover_photos.is_published (the null one doesn't count).

```
SELECT COUNT(cover_photos.is_published), COUNT(dr_id)
FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
6   3
```

This still makes sense: 6 cover_photos.is_published, 3 dr_id.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT cover_photos.is_published, dr_id
  FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
)
3
```

This is interesting too: If we do a sub-query, COUNT(*) looks at the number of rows returned. There were 3 rows returned. That still makes sense.

But then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(cover_photos.is_published)
FROM (
  SELECT cover_photos.is_published, dr_id
  FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
)
7   6
```

7 and 6. Seven? Why 7?

Well, BigQuery had to choose a flatten strategy for the subquery. Look at the table I pasted up there - can you see how it kind of has 7 rows? Those are the seven rows counted.

Let's look at them explicitly:

```
SELECT dr_id, cover_photos.is_published
FROM (
  SELECT cover_photos.is_published, dr_id
  FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]
)
```

[image]

See? Those are the seven rows. When choosing rows that have nested records (a nice feature for BigQuery), BigQuery sometimes needs to flatten the data to process certain queries. The first 2 rows got flattened to exactly 2 rows (one with a cover_photos.is_published as null), and the 3rd row got flattened to 5 rows, one for each of its cover_photos.is_published.

The moral of the story is to be careful when working with nested data: Some queries will flatten it in ways that are unexpected to the user, but that make a lot of sense to a computer when its trying to decide.

---

By request, let's go deeper:

Look at the difference between these 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]  
    WHERE is_published
  ) 
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count]  
  ) 
)
WHERE is_published
```

Before looking at the results, can you guess what results each query will give you? No, you can't. Both queries are ambiguous, so in order to get an answer BigQuery will need to make some guesses and optimizations.

The result for the first query is 7, and for the second one is 3. Go and try.

What's the difference? Well, from looking at the results of these queries, I can tell that in the second one BigQuery saw that the only column you are interested in is 'is_published', so it optimizes the tree so only that column is read. But BigQuery has a harder time optimizing the first query - so it guesses "maybe they really want *, and * means I need to flatten the table before passing it to the next layer". It flattens the table, so later the upper most query sees 7 rows.

Is any of these results guaranteed? No - the queries are ambiguous. How to reduce ambiguity? Instead of using "SELECT *", tell BigQuery which columns you want to look for - so it doesn't need to guess for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation but it doesn't quite answer the question. Can you explain why my query 1 and query 3 return different results? Neither of them explicitly reference a repeated field and the non-repeated fields in the where clause (is_claimed and is_published) are both true for every row.

Comment: I added more text, please tell me if that's better.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the moral of the story is don't use count(*) with a select * subquery. I still don't understand why replacing is_published with is_claimed in my first query gives a different result... but I think your argument is that the queries are ambiguous so you shouldn't try to analyse the results. (IMHO, it might be worth adding to the documentation -- or, In an ideal world, you'd return an error instead of results for a query that you deem ambiguous).

Comment: Actually, I found a counter-example where count(*) gives strange results even without the select *. I added these to my question, as the formatting wasn't working in the comment. It seems like the safe option is not to use count(*). Any comments, @FelipeHoffa?

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a new answer, as you keep adding elements to the question - they all deserve a different answer.

You say this query surprises you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(0)
FROM (
  SELECT dr_id, cover_photos.is_published
  FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count] )
```

You are surprised because the results are 7 and 3.

Maybe it will make sense if I try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(0), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(cover_photos.is_published)),
       GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(dr_id)), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(STRING(cover_photos.is_published),'null')),
       GROUP_CONCAT("0")
FROM (
  SELECT dr_id, cover_photos.is_published
  FROM [realself-main:rs_public.test_count] 
)
```

See? It's the same query, plus 4 different aggregations of the same sub-columns, one of which consists of nested repeated data, and that also has a null value in one row.

The results of the query are:

```
7   3   1,1,1,0,0,0 1234,4321,9999  null,1,1,1,0,0,0    0,0,0
```

The 7 comes from the full expansion of the nested data into 7 rows, as the 5th column hints. The 3 comes from just evaluating "0" three times, as can be seen on the 6th column.

These subtleties are all related to working with nested repeated data. I'll advise you to not work with nested repeated data until you are ready to accept that these subtleties can happen when working with nested repeated data.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I like the GROUP_CONCAT() trick for exploring what's going on here but the bit I was confused about is why adding COUNT(0) to the query changes the result of COUNT(*) from 3 to 7. If COUNT(*) is supposed to return count of the most-repeated field in the query and COUNT(0) returns the number of full records, then why would adding a COUNT(0) to the query change the value of COUNT(*)? It's a somewhat academic discussion at this point, as I'm unlikely to ever want to use the two count measures in a single query, but I would love to better understand this.

Comment: Hi Alan - sidenote: Are you related to this launch? http://www.looker.com/blog/big-query-launch-blog. Great blog post, and celebrating the news here :)

Comment: I don't work for Looker but I am a passionate customer... it's a great product

Comment: They certainly included some jabs to the nested records subtleties. I'm wondering - have you seen nested records implemented somewhere else and how do they behave instead?