# Counting session from each page from the data exported to bigquery from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have been trying to count the session for each page using bigquery where data is exported to bigquery from GA. The schema of the data can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en).

I have tried following query

```
SELECT
    hits.page.pagePath AS page,
    COUNT(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM
    [xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20160801]
WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, r'(orderComplete|checkout)')
    AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
GROUP BY 
    page
ORDER BY
    sessions DESC
```

I compared the result of the query with numbers that I get from the GA but the result is quite different. I expected that above query would give total session for each page but it gives total `pageviews` for each page. In other words result of above query exactly match with `pageviews` of each page instead of `sessions` of each page.

I also tried the following query

```
SELECT
    hits.page.pagePath AS page,
    COUNT(hits.isEntrance) AS sessions
FROM
    [xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20160801]
WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, r'(orderComplete|checkout)')
    AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
GROUP BY 
    page
ORDER BY
    sessions DESC
```

The result this time is very close to actual but not exactly the same as numbers that I am getting from GA. This time bigquery result is slightly less than that of the GA for some pages.

**There is no sampling in GA in my case otherwise result is acceptable because error is between 0.5% to 4%**

I am working with raw data without any filter on GA profile and same data is exported to bigquery.

> Question: How is session counted when we count session by pages?

When I don't group the result by `hits.page.pagePath` there is no mismatch of results that I get from GA and that from bigquery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `COUNT(totals.visits)`, what if you use `COUNT(1)`? The results of `COUNT` will vary depending on whether you are using a repeated field. Possibly relevant question with some in depth answers: [BigQuery flattens when using field with same name as repeated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604080/bigquery-flattens-when-using-field-with-same-name-as-repeated-field/)

As an aside, standard SQL (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") has less surprising semantics around counting, although it would require you to be more explicit with [operations on arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/arrays) in this case.

Comment: Actually `count(totals.visits)` is the correct way to count session according to description in bigquery export schema. `COUNT(1)` will count both session with interaction and without interaction. But in GA only session with interaction aggregated to display total session.

Answer (score 0):

To count sessions, I use `COUNT(visitId)` instead of `COUNT(totals.visits)`. This seems to give me numbers identical--or very, very close--to what I see in GA.

Comment: `visitId` is only unique to user. For a completely unique session identifier we have to use concatenation of `fullVisitorId` and `visitId`. For more information you can see description of `visitId` here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Comment: Right you are! I had missed that it's possible for visitId to be repeated across two different visitors, resulting in a lower count of sessions if that was the case.