# Implicit Flattening in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When does BigQuery flatten an intermediate result set?  I was under the impression that it was only when `FLATTEN` was invoked, but I've encountered an example where the result is flattened without a `FLATTEN`.

This is the case - this base query returns one record:

```
select count(*) from publicdata:samples.trigrams 
where ngram = 'der Griindung im'
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
```

When queried, you can see that the record has a repeated field that is repeated twice.

```
select * from publicdata:samples.trigrams 
where ngram = 'der Griindung im'
+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|      ngram       | first |  second   | third | fourth | fifth | cell_value | cell_volume_count | cell_volume_fraction | cell_page_count | cell_match_count | cell_sample_id | cell_sample_text | cell_sample_title | cell_sample_subtitle | cell_sample_authors | cell_sample_url |
+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| der Griindung im | der   | Griindung | im    | NULL   | NULL  | 2007       |                54 | 0.008746355685131196 |              54 |               54 | NULL           | NULL             | NULL              | NULL                 | NULL                | NULL            |
| der Griindung im | der   | Griindung | im    | NULL   | NULL  | 2008       |                47 | 0.007612568837058633 |              47 |               47 | NULL           | NULL             | NULL              | NULL                 | NULL                | NULL            |
+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

When I add a filter on `cell.value`, I get two records instead of one - but I never flattened so I'm not sure about the behavior here.  My expectation is that this would return the same output as the previous `COUNT` above.  It doesn't:

```
select count(*) from publicdata:samples.trigrams 
where ngram = 'der Griindung im' and cell.value in ('2007', '2008')
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   2 |
+-----+
```

What this means is that while I expect `select * from publicdata:samples.trigrams where ngram = 'der Griindung im'` and `select * from publicdata:samples.trigrams where ngram = 'der Griindung im' and cell.value in ('2007', '2008')` to return the same output, they don't because one is implicitly flattened and the other is not.  While this may not seem like a huge issue, this could matter significantly if it was part of a nested query that expected an intermediate result to be flattened or repeated.

Under what conditions does BigQuery flatten results without an explicit `FLATTEN`?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer first, how to get correct count in this case:

So instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE ngram = 'der Griindung im' 
AND cell.value IN ('2007', '2008')
```

with result of

```
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   2 |
+-----+
```

you should do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE ngram = 'der Griindung im' 
OMIT RECORD IF EVERY(cell.value NOT IN ('2007', '2008'))
```

with result of

```
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
```

as I think what you expected

Secondly - `Under what conditions does BigQuery flatten results without an explicit FLATTEN?`

I think (just my guess baseed on BQ behavior observation) every time you explicitelly reference record's field within clauses like SELECT or WHERE , it gets automatically flattened for you. Using FLATTEN operator helps "control" this process.

Answer (score 1):

Short story: use `count(0)` instead of `count(*)`. (You get `1` instead of `2`.)

`count(*)` behaves strangely with repeated fields. It looks like the results are flattened, but if that were really the case, this should also affect `count(0)`. I've asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483766/how-exactly-is-the-value-of-count-determined-in-bigquery), but I haven't so far received a full explanation.